# How to write short alpha using the compose key

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, input, compose-key

I'd like to enter a short alpha using the compose key: ᾰ. I tried using compose+U+α but this doesn't work. Neither does using b instead of U.

How can I enter the short alpha using the compose key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U+1FB0 is not in the X.org standard compose map.

You can define your own compose map by creating a file `.XCompose` in your home directory. See [UTF8 math symbols & keyboard layout / input](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21994/utf8-math-symbols-keyboard-layout-input/22037#22037)
 for more details. Copy the default file from `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose` (the location may be different in different distributions) and a line like

```
<Multi_key> <a> <u> : U1fb0 # "ᾰ"
```

Alternatively, you can try another [input method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method) (Xim, Gtkim, Scim, …). I don't know which common input method has ᾰ by default or can easily be customized.

Comment: Do I need this hex code or can I stick with this "ᾰ" only?

Comment: @marmistrz I'm not sure. Looking at the Compose(5) man page, I think in principle you should use only the hex code and not the string: with no string, a string is automatically generated from the hex code according to the current locale, whereas if you specify a string, it is inserted no matter what the locale is. For example, with `"ᾰ" U1fb0` or just plain `"ᾰ"`, in a latin-1 locale, `á¾°` is inserted, whereas with just `U1fb0` nothing is inserted. By the way, beware that I made a typo in my initial answer: the file name is `.XCompose` with a capital C.

Comment: I noticed that the Compose file uses <Greek_alpha> to add alpha variations. I added this `<Multi_key> <Greek_alpha> <u> : U1fb0 # ᾰ` to the end of the file, but new windows can't compose this character.

Comment: @marmistrz Do you have both `α` and `u` on your keyboard at the same time? Maybe you're typing `Compose α υ`?