# input method to type math symbols?

Tags: debian, x11, keyboard

Is there some input method to easily type math symbols UTF8 characters (like *U+2200 FOR ALL* **∀**, *U+2203 THERE EXISTS* **∃**, 
*U+2208 ELEMENT OF* **∈**, *U+2190 LEFTWARDS ARROW* **←**, etc...)?

I would like to type easily these characters in some `<textarea>` in Firefox (38 or 42) on Debian/Linux/x86_64 under xfce4 or Gnome (and I want to avoid Javascript tricks for that). I am currently copy/pasting them from some CharacterMap application, which is uneasy.

The answers to [this related](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21994/50557) question requires some ad-hoc configuration; I am asking for a *standard* input method.

Comment: I think compose key + character code  is the way to go. You can't possibly have dedicated key, or key combo for that matter, for every unicode characters.

Comment: what do you mean by *standard* input method?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:  press ctrl-shft-U and then type the 4-digit code.  This works on my Gnome shell desktop (Fedora 20, though).  For example, when I type ctl-shft-U 2203 and then hit the space bar, it gives me ∃ .   See http://library.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/tips-specialchars.html.en

Comment: That could work, but is not very user friendly. I was thinking of some "input mode" (or simply Javascript browser code) which perhaps would allow me to type `\forall` followed by the *escape* key, or something similar.